# Blending Object Colors in Unity

Tags: unity, color, alpha-blending

I'm completely new to Game Development but I'm required to use Unity for a class project. For the project I want multiple spheres of different colors to overlap each other and create new colors in the overlapping space. Ex: where a red and blue sphere overlap, it turns purple; where a red and yellow sphere overlap, it turns orange.

I have the spheres and I've tried multiple different shaders and blend modes to try to achieve this but haven't been able to get the effect I'm looking for.

This is what I've been able to make so far [image: failed attempts]

And here's a mock-up what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: mock-up]
Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Do these spheres also need to blend/coexist with anything in the rest of the scene, or is it just these against a plain background as you've visualized here?

Comment: They just need to blend with themselves. They'll be against a flat white background.